# In cmake, can we avoid using find_package to import other packages?

Tags: c++, c, cmake

Okay, the title is obviously weird. I hope anyone who can define my curiosity cleanly, would edit the title into proper one.

When using CMakeLists.txt, we usually import third-party packages via command `find_package()` macro, which looks for proper `find_XXX.cmake` script, and then results outputting variables such as `XXX_LIBRARIES`, `XXX_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`, etc.

However, recently I found some instruction guide for `add_library()` macro, that can include actual library binaries as its source(?), like this way:

```
add_library(my_target STATIC IMPORTED foo.lib)
```

And as I guess, as long as the name `my_target` is actually names a target, then we can add another compositions into that target, like any other cmake targets, like below.

```
target_inlcude_directories(my_target PUBLIC ${PKG_PREFIX}/include)
target_link_directories(my_target PUBLIC ${PKG_PREFIX}/lib)
target_compile_features(my_target PUBLIC std_cxx_17)
```

If this is possible, then wouldn't this be much cleaner way to describe exported package's compositions, rather than linking and adding those verbose `*_LIBS` `*_DIRS` variables manually for each? Like below?

```
add_executable(foo ${MY_SOURCES})
find_package(xxx)

# BEFORE
target_link_directories(foo PRIVATE ${XXX_LINK_DIRECTORIES}) # note: I don't remember what was it exactly.
target_link_libraries(foo PRIVATE ${XXX_LIBRARIES})
target_include_directories(foo PRIVATE ${XXX_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES})

# AFTER
target_link_libraries(foo PRIVATE xxx::my_target)
```

Am I thinking something invalid?

Comment: That depends on whether the package exposes targets. Many do. Example: [openssl](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindOpenSSL.html) defines `OpenSSL::SSL` and `OpenSSL::Crypto`. You use that instead of `OPENSSL_SSL_LIBRARY`. Not all do though, then you're back to the old way.

Comment: Ah, was it already widely used method? Thanks, I didn't know it. I'll close this question ... sorry, but can I close this without any accepted answers?

Comment: Nice read for modern cmake practices: https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/ (and I believe you may delete your own question if it is no longer useful, or wait for someone to make an answer — I won't, gotta leave right now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can we avoid using find_package to import other packages?

You can, but it's the tool to be used just for that. `find_package()` is basically an `include()` with some special options.

> wouldn't this be much cleaner way to describe exported package's compositions, rather than linking and adding those verbose *_LIBS *_DIRS variables manually for each? Like below?

It would be and it is used.

`cmake` is still ongoing relative big changes in a very short time. I think interface libraries weren't so popular or weren't available some time ago. The *only* (except some checks, etc) thing `find_package` does is it includes a file named `FindXXX.cmake` (or other file named differently). *Only*. It's completely dependent on what's inside the `FindXXX.cmake` file what happens.

Newer cmake `FindXXX.cmake` does exactly what you propose: they create an `INTERFACE IMPORTED` library, for example on my pc:

```
@/usr/share/cmake-3.20/Modules
$ grep add_library -wr --include='Find*' .
.... a lot of results ....
./FindBoost.cmake:    add_library(Boost::diagnostic_definitions INTERFACE IMPORTED)
./FindBoost.cmake:    add_library(Boost::disable_autolinking INTERFACE IMPORTED)
./FindBoost.cmake:    add_library(Boost::dynamic_linking INTERFACE IMPORTED)
./FindThreads.cmake:  add_library(Threads::Threads INTERFACE IMPORTED)
./FindHDF5.cmake:    add_library(HDF5::HDF5 INTERFACE IMPORTED)
./FindHDF5.cmake:        add_library("hdf5::${hdf5_target_name}" INTERFACE IMPORTED)
./FindHDF5.cmake:        add_library("hdf5::${hdf5_target_name}" UNKNOWN IMPORTED)
./FindHDF5.cmake:        add_library("hdf5::${hdf5_target_name}" INTERFACE IMPORTED)
./FindHDF5.cmake:        add_library("hdf5::${hdf5_target_name}" UNKNOWN IMPORTED)
./FindGTest.cmake:        add_library(GTest::GTest INTERFACE IMPORTED)
./FindGTest.cmake:        add_library(GTest::Main INTERFACE IMPORTED)
./FindGTest.cmake:        add_library(GTest::gtest ${GTEST_LIBRARY_TYPE} IMPORTED)
./FindGTest.cmake:        add_library(GTest::gtest_main ${GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARY_TYPE} IMPORTED)
./FindBZip2.cmake:    add_library(BZip2::BZip2 UNKNOWN IMPORTED)
```

Older or "more standard" (ie. older :) indeed create multiple variables - `XXX_LINK_DIRECTORIES` `XXX_LIBRARIES` etc. Note that does variable names *are not the same* everywhere (`XXX_LIB`? `XXX_INC_DIRS`? etc.) and change depending on which `FindXXX.cmake` you call because some developers decided on different names. A lot of documentation was written in the time the `find_package` used variables, so it's still visible in documentation, but nowadays interface libraries clearly dominate and what you propose is already used.

Comment: _"Note that does variable names are not the same everywhere"_ That was true in the past, but these days the CMake documentation explicitly specifies the [Standard Variable Names](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/manual/cmake-developer.7.html#id9) and how to use them. Their bundled Find modules have all been standardized. And since Find modules shouldn't be installed by third parties, any others will usually be project-local ones. If a local module uses non-standard vars, fix it! (But using `IMPORTED` targets is always preferable, of course.)

Comment: (Note that `CONFIG`-mode package definitions _will_ sometimes bundle local `Find` modules for their own use, if they need to configure non-CMake dependencies. But those aren't on the outer project's `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`, so they're only accessible to the `CONFIG`-mode package. Whatever they do with variables, standard or non-, is its problem to deal with. Anything the package needs to pass along should be included in the `IMPORTED` targets it provides to the caller.)

Answer (score 1):

Note that the imported library is not set up properly in this case. Configuration scripts (`<packageName>Config.cmake`) which are used as fallback for `find_package` or if you use the `CONFIG` version usually do exactly this: create one or more imported targets for you to use in your project. I strongly recommend using those instead of the `*_LIBS`/`*_DIRS` variables, if available.

Here's the correct version of importing the library:

```
add_library(my_target STATIC IMPORTED)

# INTERFACE "visibility" needed here;
# also quote the path concatenation to avoid issues with spaces in PKG_PREFIX
target_include_directories(my_target INTERFACE "${PKG_PREFIX}/include")
target_link_directories(my_target INTERFACE "${PKG_PREFIX}/lib")

# do you really need the linking library to use the C++ 17 standard?
target_compile_features(my_target INTERFACE std_cxx_17)

# you need specify the absolute path to the lib as IMPORTED_LOCATION target property
# you may need to adjust the location according to the exact location of the lib file
#
# variables CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR (if used from CMakeLists.txt) or
# CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR (if used from a script) may be helpful
#
# requires seperate treatment for different OS; this is not included here
set_target_properties(my_target PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${PKG_PREFIX}/lib/my_target.a")
```

Note that in this case the library you need to link is `my_target`, not `xxx::my_target`.